# Source Tree - shows annoying popup after almost each action

Tags: git, sourcetree

I am using source tree as my versioning tool with git.

I noticed that I always get a popup after trivial actions like creating a new branch. It is annoying and I always have to close it to be able to proceed.

[image]

Is there a way to make it only show important popups?

Tested Versions: 3.4.7 / 3.4.9

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this behaviour by unchecking `Always display full console output`:

*Tools -> Options -> Tab: General -> Section: Repo Settings -> Always display full console output*